# Selenium Python3 Bruteforce Login with 2 seperate text files. ERROR

Tags: python, selenium, textinput

(I am new to selenium and python)
I have usernames.text and passwords.txt files for input credentials. When run, username field is working but password field is not working.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
browser.get(URL);

with open('usernames.txt') as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()



for l in lines1:
    username = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
    username.send_keys(l)

    with open('passwords.txt') as f2:
        lines2 = f2.readlines()

    for m in lines2:
        password = browser.find_element_by_name('pass')
        password.send_keys(m)
        time.sleep(1)
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Error 404 no error reported

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *password field is not working.* -- is there some error?

Also, can you provide sample contents of `usernames.txt` and `passwords.txt` so we may reproduce the behavior?